# Live console output with colors on jenkins with pytest

Tags: jenkins, pytest, ansi-colors, console-output

How to see to console output in live on jenkins with pytest?

**Important note:**
I need also to see the colors with AnsiColor and I see them with this command:

```
pytest [path_to_test] --capture tee-sys
```

But it's not in live

IF I run this command:

```
pytest -s [path_to_test]
```

Then I don't see the colors however console output is live

The **QUESTION IS** - how to run capture-sys in live on jenkins with pytest???

Thanks in advance